# Limiting the frames per second for a text based game running in command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, frame-rate, game-loop

This is a follow up question to the comments in my last question. I was told that the command prompt screen is flickering because i didnt limit the frames per second. I have been doing some research on how to limit frames per second and i found this:

```
def limit_frames(FPS): 
    return 1/ FPS

while True: # The main game loop
    # rest of the code
    time.sleep(limit_frames())
```

`Limit_frames` is an inverse function that returns smaller value if the FPS is greater, and this returned value is used in the main  loop as an argument to `time.sleep`, so that greater FPS input to `limit_frames`
function lowers the sleep time, hence more frames.
However, this still dosent work for me and the window is still flickering. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit :

This is the map class:

```
    class Map:
        def __init__(self):
            self.map = [[" " for i in range(50)]for i in range(40)]
            self.n = 0 # counter used for boundry

        def update(self, thing, x, y):  
            self.map[y][x] = thing


        def draw(self):
            for layer in self.map: 
                for item in layer:
                    print(item, end= " ") 
                print('')


        def boundry(self):
            for i in range(50): # TOP
                self.update("_", self.n, 0)
                self.n += 1
                if self.n >= 49:
                    self.n = 0

            for i in range(40): # LEFT
                self.update("|", 0, self.n)
                self.n += 1
                if self.n >= 39:
                    self.n = 0

            for i in range(40): # RIGHT
                self.update("|", 49, self.n)
                self.n += 1
                if self.n >= 39:
                    self.n = 0

            for i in range(50): # BOTTOM
                self.update("_", self.n, 39)
                self.n += 1
                if self.n >= 49:
                    self.n = 0
```

I am using the update function to update the map. I have called it in  different classes to such as player to add them to the map.An example is as follows:

```
    def draw(self):
        game_map.update(self.player, self.x, self.y)
```

The following is the entire game loop:

```
start = time.time()
FPS = 10000
while True:
    end = time.time()
    difference = end - start

    game_map.draw()
    game_map.boundry()

    os.system("cls")
    player.draw()
    player.move()
    player.boundries()
    player.print_score()

    game.generate_bullet()
    game.shoot()
    game.bullet_boundries()



    game.generate_enemies(difference)
    game.draw_enemies()
    game.move_enemies()
    game.enemy_boundries()
    game.hit()

    time.sleep(1/FPS)
```

Comment: It sounds like the rate at which you update the screen is the main cause of the flicker. Perhaps it _how_ you update the text screen (or what the library does it if you're using one).

Comment: @martineau I updated the question with how i am updating the text screen

Comment: Also i tried different numbers as FPS ranging from  1 to a few thousand and none of them provide  a stable screen.

Comment: That's what I said, it's not how fast or slow you're updating the screen that's causing it to flicker — so FPS doesn't matter.

Comment: I cant think of any other way to update the screen to reduce flickering :(

Comment: Your code clears the screen with an `os.system("cls")` each frame and then redraws it. That alone may cause the flickering because of the inherent need to simulate a text console on a Windows' graphical display (which is what the `cmd` prompt does).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207882/discussion-between-hippozhipos-and-martineau).

Answer (score 0):

you should run `time.timeit(run)` in that run is your game script so when It finishes you do

```py
time.sleep(1/fps-run_time if 1/fps-run_time>0 else 0)
```

Comment: Please make sure that your codes are in a correct format.